# AdminLTE Installation With Bower

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, bower, adminlte

I was installing Admin LTE Template for my Laravel project.
I follow the instructions from [here](https://adminlte.io/blog/integrate-adminlte-with-laravel)
When I type the syntax:

```
bower install admin-lte
```

It started to download or something, but the cmd need more action. It says:

```
Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json

? Answer
```

This is the capture of my CMD
[image]

What should I type for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please you should type `6` number as answer then create new folder (i.e bower_components) in your public folder

**Note**: Please `bower install admin-lte` command run your public path
(i.e `yourproject/public/`)

Comment: @GeraldSihotang: Glad to help and please upvote to my answer